# Login required in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am developing ecommerce website in django .
I have view ( addToCart)
I want sure before add to cart if user logged in or not 
so that i use @login_required('login') before view
but when click login it show error (can't access to page ).

Note that: normal login is working

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us the error text and traceback. Without those, we can't help.

Comment: If you are using django in-build authentication than you can only do this. @login_required

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following
1. Add login url on settings
2. Add redirect url on login required decorator
3. If you create a custom login view make sure to check next kwargs